# Firestore Firebase create fielID equal Document ID

Tags: flutter

Can anyone tell me how to create a field Id that is equal to the Document ID.  I have done like below however is very inconsistent sometimes the documentID is equal field ID other times not. I want them to always be the save.

```
  void saveOrders() async {
    await _db.collection(_collectionOrders).add(
        {
          "id": _db.collection(_collectionOrders).document().documentID,
        }
        ).then((value){
    });
  }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in two steps:

1. Create your `document` without the `id`:

   `DocumentReference doc = await _db.collection(_collectionOrders).add({'your': 'data'});`
2. Update the newly created `document` and add the `id` property:

   `await doc.update({'id': doc.id});`

You can now be sure that you inserted the right `documentId`.